# Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional - How to Uninstall VBScript Runtime Library and Install again?

Tags: mobile, vbscript, extensions, arcpad, trimble

I've been having trouble getting the Trimble Positions for ArcPad Extension to correctly install on my Trimble Geo 7X handheld. I saw that another user asked about something similar and the solution provided was to re-install VBScript Runtime Library. I've gotten that far, but can't find a way to re-install it.

What is says:

```
Script Error 800A01A8

Error Source Unavailable    
Error Description Unavailable    
[Line: 61, Column: 4]    
Source Text Unavailable
```

Also, upon exiting ArcPad, it throws another error popup that references Line: 41, Column: 5. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I guess that the VBScript library is installed as part of ArcPad.  I don't have ArcPad on a Geo 7x at the oment so I can't confirm it, but if that is the case, I think the only way to reinstall the VBScript library would be to uninstall ArcPad and reinstall ArcPad.

As a last resort you could do a factory reset of the Geo7x OS then reinstall everything.